# Git merge direction for develop/feature branches

Tags: git, merge

My current workflow for when I have a merge conflict it

```
 git checkout develop
    git pull origin develop
    git checkout feature-branch
    git merge develop
    git push origin feature-branch
```

with a recent code review, my branch was unaware that files in develop had been deleted/moved.  Is this the correct way to merge? Or should I merge feature-branch into develop and push develop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge `develop` into `feature` your procedure is correct.
Be careful: You did not use `pull origin feature`. Perhaps this part introduced errors because you merged your local (that is not up-to-date) copy of `feature`.

If you work with others it might be helpful if you always

- commit your local change you want to introduce (1st branch for merge)
- push your local change to the remote
- checkout and pull the other branch (2nd branch for merge)